# How to set new adapter to expandable listview after already set adapter?

Tags: android

How to set new adapter to expandable listview after already set adapter ?
I set adapter to expandable listview with data but after refresh I set new adapter and call

```
expList.postInvalidate();
```

but it doesn't show new data. I tried with `invalidate()`, `notify()`, but it doesn't work.
How to set new adapter with data to expandable listview.

Comment: Just set another adapter. Like the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the method

notifyDataSetChanged() --> [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

When the adapter's data has changed, you have to execute this method on the adapter.